# How Do I Combine The Date Into The URL Using PHP

Tags: php, date, substr

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$url = substr($url,0,10);
```

This produces a URL like this:

domain.com/my-web-pag.php

What I would like to do is some how figure out a way to add the date into the URL

```
date('m-d-y');
```

so that the final url would look like this:

domain.com/10-03-12-my-web-pag.php

Would someone mind helping piece that code together for me? I greatly appreciate any one who is willing to help. Thank you!

Comment: `$url = date('m-d-y-').substr($url,0,10)`

Comment: Thank you... you should have posted that as the answer. Ben below provided the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = date('m-d-y-').substr($url,0,10);
```

This will show something like site.com/10-29-12-my-web-pag.php

Comment: Perfect... that's just what I needed. Thank you very much Ben.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark as answered if you're happy :)

Comment: I been waiting to.. I have two minutes left to wait until I can. And yes, I am MORE than happy to. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$str = 'domain.com/my-web-pag.php';
$arr = explode('/',$str);
$url = $arr[0] . '/' . date('m-d-y') . '-' . $arr[1];
echo $url; // outputs domain.com/10-03-12-my-web-pag.php
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for taking the time to write an answer.